# How do I numerically integrate over a data set that has uncertainties?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerics

I have a 1D data set  {xi, yi}  with no uncertainties in  xi  and with uncertainties  dyi  in  yi.  The resulting discrete function is monotonic and relatively smooth and I would like to integrate the function.

If there were no uncertainties, I would interpolate the data (either interpolation order 1 or 2) and then numerically integrate the interpolated function.  But what do I do when there are uncertainties?  My guess is that this is a well-studied problem but I can locate any references.  Do you know of any references?

Here are my two thoughts on how I could proceed.

1. Quick technique.  Look at two other data sets  {xi, yi + dyi}  and  {xi, yi - dyi} which bound the original set.  Interpolate and integrate as before.  This would give an upper and lower bound to the integral.
2. More involved technique.  For each value of  xi,  draw a value of  yi'  from a normal distribution with mean  yi  and standard deviation  dyi.  Then interpolate and integrate.  Do this a large number of times and find the average value and its standard deviation.

Hope this makes sense.  Comments?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: Is it possible that this Question belongs in the Math or Statistics sections of SE?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue it raises is not a  _Mathematica_ issue but a mathematics one. That the question's poster plans to apply _Mathematica_ to it is not sufficient to make it an appropriate question for _Mathematica_.SE.

Comment: I would not be opposed to keeping the question here, but I think that OP will receive a better answer more quickly on one of the other sites. Therefore I concur with the closing.